# PHP Array index addition - different levels

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have 2 arrays as follows :-

```
$m_aggregate = array(
             'weighted' => array (40000,
                   30000,
                   90000,
                   0),
      'unweighted' => array (3000,
                     2000,
                     6000,
                     0),
      'weighted_sum' => 160000,
      'unweighted_sum' => 11000
     );

$f_aggregate = array(
             'weighted' => array (7000,
                           5000,
                           9000,
                           0),
      'unweighted' => array (500,
                            300,
                            600,
                            0),
      'weighted_sum' => 21000,
      'unweighted_sum' => 1400
     );
```

and wish to sum the individual elements so I get

```
$tot_aggregate = array(
             'weighted' => array (47000,
                          35000,
                      99000,
                  0),
      'unweighted' => array (3500,
                            2300,
                6600,
                0),
      'weighted_sum' => 181000,
      'unweighted_sum' => 12400
     );
```

I've tried using

```
function sum($arr1, $arr2)
{
    return($arr1+$arr2);
}

$tot_aggregate = array_map("sum", $m_aggregate, $f_aggregate);

print_r($tot_aggregate);
```

but this gives me weighted_sum and unweighted_sum , but not the weighted and unweighted arrays within the array summed.

Can anyone help?
tia
Jas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sum($arr1, $arr2)
{
    return is_array( $arr1) && is_array( $arr2)  
           ? array_map("sum", $arr1, $arr2) 
           : ($arr1 + $arr2); 

}

$tot_aggregate = sum($m_aggregate, $f_aggregate);

print_r($tot_aggregate);
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 47000
            [1] => 35000
            [2] => 99000
            [3] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3500
            [1] => 2300
            [2] => 6600
            [3] => 0
        )

    [2] => 181000
    [3] => 12400
)
```

Comment: Som - is there a way to get the array key names 'weighted', 'unweighted' , 'weighted_sum', 'unweighted_sum' in the required output using your function?