# PHP Array index addition - different levels - copying array Names also

Tags: php, arrays

In [PHP Array index addition - different levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996064/php-array-index-addition-different-levels)

is there a  way to get array key names 'weighted', 'unweighted' , 'weighted_sum', 'unweighted_sum' rather than array index numbers?

So in the required output rather than   [0] => Array,  [1] => Array,  [2] => , 
 [3] =>

is there a way to get 'weighted' => Array,   'unweighted' => Array, 'weighted_sum' =>   ,  'unweighted_sum' =>

tia
Jas

Comment: sure. there's a way to do pretty much anything you want. what have you tried? where are you stuck?

Comment: original answer was function sum($arr1, $arr2)
{
    return is_array( $arr1) && is_array( $arr2)  
           ? array_map("sum", $arr1, $arr2) 
           : ($arr1 + $arr2); 

}

$tot_aggregate = sum($m_aggregate, $f_aggregate);

print_r($tot_aggregate); which was great, but didn't retain the array key names..

Comment: Why did you accept the last answer if it wasn't what you wanted?

Comment: It looked like the answer I needed and indeed sums correctly, but an additional reqt has come along where the array key names need retaining.

Comment: so ... have you tried anything? where are you stuck?

Comment: new to php arrays - have tried setting structure of array i want eg $mytot_aggregate = array('weighted'=>array(0,0,0,0),
                         'unweighted'=>array(0,0,0,0),
    'weighted_sum'=>0,
    'unweighted_sum'=>0);   and then $mytot_aggregate = $tot_aggregate but that just overides it with the array index numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$keys = array_keys($m_aggregate);
$tot_aggregate = sum($m_aggregate, $f_aggregate);
$tot_aggregate = array_combine($keys, $tot_aggregate);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$array=array(

'weighted' => 'x',
'unweighted' => 'y',
'weighted_sum' => 'z'

);


echo $array['weighted'];
```

Multidimensional arrays
http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/multidimensional_arrays.php